Matrix of a linear transformation in a different basis.

I was looking up how to do this and found this video on khan academy titled
Transformation matrix with respect to a basis
I just want to make sure that this is the correct way to solve this question, namely that to find the matrix that represents the transformation in a different basis you use the equation:
D = C-1AC
Where
D = the transformation matrix L with respect to the basis B.
B = {<1,2,0>, <0,2,3>, <2,0,5>}
A = the transformation matrix with respect to the standard basis.
  = <1 3 -1>
    <1 0 -3>
    <4 -5 0>
  = I derived that from the L(x,y,z).
C = change of basis matrix = basis vectors as columns
  = < 1 0 2 >
    < 2 2 0 >
    < 0 3 5 >
C^-1 = < 5/11 3/11 -2/11
        -5/11 5/22 2/11
         3/11 -3/22 1/11 >

and d =
50/11   8/11    -70/11
-89/22  -115/22 -3/22
27/22   25/22    37/22


This is a terribly written post. We shouldn't have to watch a video and you haven't defined what $A$, $C$, $D$ or $c$ are. It is better to show your work. It doesn't matter where you learned the material.

I'll add more context I guess, I thought terminology was consistent across different sources so I didn't think I had to repeat it again. I wasn't expecting you to watch the video, I told you that the matrix of a transformation in a different basis is C-1AC, specifically so you didn't have to watch it.

I didn't check your numbers but yes, $C^{-1}AC$ is correct. The idea is that $C$ transforms a vector from the new basis to the standard basis, $A$ transforms a vector in the standard frame, and $C^{-1}$ transforms the result of $A$ from the standard frame back to the new basis. Note that $c\ne C$. Mathematics is case sensitive.

@JohnDouma The reason I'm asking is because I'm comparing my homework with other people in my class and I'm doing something completely different than what they are doing.  Not only is their strategy different, but so are their answers.
Is there a different way to calculate D?

This is correct. How are they doing it? A good way to check if your procedure is correct is to use transformations, where you know the answer. You can, for example, look for a worked example online and ignore their procedure and do it your way. If it works, you are probably doing it correctly. You must also be very careful when doing these transformations. There is a lot of arithmetic that gives you a chance to make a simple mistake that can change the final answer drastically.

@JohnDouma They are applying the transformation L to every vector in the basis, and then composing the transformation matrix in a basis b (LB) as columns of those vectors. For example, for the first basis vector <1,2,0> they are applying L(1,2,0) = <7, 1, -6>
L(0,2,3) = <3, -9, -10>
L(2,0,5) = <-3,-13,8>
LB =
7   3   -3
1  -9   -13
-6 -10  8

That gives $AC$ which is a vector in the standard frame. They must still apply $C^{-1}$ to get back to the new basis.

omg, I just checked. When you apply c inverse to that (AC) you get my answer.
Thanks
Are these two different strategies? When I tried googling the answer I came up with that Khan Academy video, but the video doesn't ever mention applying the basis vectors into the transformation. Better yet, can you point me to a resource that does what they were doing, and explains the reasoning behind it?
Also, how are you using latex in the comments? I tried but it's not applying properly, it works in the post but not here.
Actually, now that I think about it I can see that what they did is AC,nvm

Surround your Mathjax with dollar signs just like you do in the post. This is a good place to start. The basis vectors in any frame take the form of $b_1=(1,0,0)^T$, $b_2=(0,1,0)^T$, etc. When you multiply them by $C$ you get the vectors that your friends plugged into the transformation directly. It's not a different strategy, it is a realization of what the transformation actually does.
